# How to delete {{ $key }} with ajax in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

We have multiple hidden inputs like this with `@foreach`.

```
<form action="{{ route('parties.updateAndCreate', auth()->id()) }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    @method('PUT')
    <input type="hidden" name="category_id" value="{{ $category->id }}">
    @foreach($parties as $party)
        @foreach($party->reals as $key => $real)
            <input type="hidden" name="party_key" value="{{ $key }}">
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

And we have to click remove

```
$(document).on('click', '.fa-trash', function() {
    $("input[name='delete_parties[]']").val([$(this).attr('data-id')])
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
});
```

And when I click the save button it sends in the controller.

```
public function updateAndCreate (Request $request)
{
    dd($request->post('delete_parties'));
```

I see this.

```
^ array:6 [▼
  "_token" => "ZpfR4IetOc9teRTFFT3ScnCCWkDnBc58T0mcmeLP"
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "category_id" => "3"
  "party_key" => "0"
  "parties" => array:1 [▼
    3 => array:1 [▼
      "real_person" => array:1 [▼
        0 => array:2 [▼
          "id" => "59"
          "name" => "AA"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
  "contract_subject" => null
]
```

How can I delete that $key to dd?

```
@foreach($parties as $party)
        @foreach($party->reals as $key => $real)
            <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
                <fieldset class="border p-2">
                    <legend class="float-none w-auto p-2 pb-0 h6 fs-6 mb-0">real_person</legend>
                    <input type="hidden" name="parties[{{ $party->id }}][real_person][{{ $key }}][id]" value="{{ $real->id }}" />
                    <textarea name="parties[{{ $party->id }}][real_person][{{ $key }}][name]" id="real_person" class="form-control border-0" rows="10" aria-label="real_person">{{ $real->real_person }}</textarea>
                    <a class="cursor-pointer text-secondary"><i class="fa-solid fa-2x fa-trash"></i></a>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say, *How can I delete that $key to dd?*

Comment: I have a button for `fa-trash`.  how to pass the `$key` to `data-id`?

Answer (score 0):

if u want to reset  keys to consecutive integer need use method values()